# How do you in C++ of returning a default type for a class

Tags: c++

I have a class which contains a variable (apple). How can i configure the class so by default the return type if (const char *), any suggestions please?

```
class myClass {
   public char *apple;
}

int main()
{
   myClass c;
   printf("%s\r\n",c);
}
```

Comment: What do you man with return type? Besides of that this is no valid C++ syntax I believe.

Comment: Classes don't have something like a _default type_. Did you mean overloading the [type conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)?

Comment: Another option might be to use stream output and override the '<<' operator.

Answer (score 3):

A much nicer solution to print out your class is:

```
class Apple {
    public:
        const char* apple;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const Apple& apple) {
    return stream << apple.apple;
};

int main() {
    Apple a;
    a.apple = "Hello world";
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might want user-defined conversion which would require you overloaded member `operator const char*`, e.g.

```
operator const char *() const { return apple; }
```

Then you could do:

```
myClass a;
const char *c = a; //c becomes a->apple
```

But the question is not very clear on the exact intent.

Comment: Oh, I love this, but this is definitely not what he is asking...

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you asking:

First of all code is wrong, looks like `Java`. You need `:` after `public`

## Use constructor

```
class myClass {
public:
     myClass() : apple("Apple"){}
     myClass(const char *apple) : apple(apple){}

     // please note I changed it to be `const`, 
     // to avoid use of `strcpy()` or similar. 
     const char *apple;
}

int main() {
   myClass c;
   printf("%s\r\n", c.apple);
}
```

## Use "inline" specifier

This can not be done with `char *`, but if you are using `std::string`, then you might do it like this:

```
class myClass {
public:
     myClass(const char *apple) : apple(apple){}

     // no need to be `const`...
     std::string apple = "Apple";
}

int main() {
   myClass c;
   printf("%s\r\n", c.apple.c_str() );
}
```